# Is it possible to have a HDD with Windows 10 and a Linux fully encrypted with VeraCrypt?

Tags: multi-boot, encryption, operating-systems, disk-encryption, veracrypt

So I'd like to set up a multiboot system on my 4TB hard drive with Windows 10 64bit and a Linux distribution such as Debian and fully encrypt it with VeraCrypt. Is this possible? And if so how?

Comment: It should be possible.  Windows 10 and Linux both support VeraCrypt (MBR) I can't think of any reason them being together would be a problem.

Comment: The answer to this Q http://superuser.com/questions/1019673/how-would-i-encrypt-my-whole-linux-filesystem-with-veracrypt suggests it's faster/better to use LUKS with Linux. Since you need separate partitions for Linux & Win anyway, why not use separate encryption too?

Comment: @Xen2050 Alright then; is it true that I can't use system encryption then? Do I need to manually partition the drive or will it work with both os creating their own partition?

Comment: The answers for a Debian based linux with LUKS are in the Q linked above, and in many guides online, just search for your distribution & LUKS install. For Win, I don't know

Answer (score 0):

No. Veracrypt does not support encryption of the root partition of Linux. However, it is possible to create a fully encrypted setup, using VeraCrypt for Windows and LUKS/DM-Crypt for Linux.